# Recursive exponentiation

Tags: c, algorithm, recursion

so I have to write a recursive algorithm for exponentiation and I have to use this to make the algorithm faster: [image: http://i.imgur.com/Ig87RZ2.png] and then I'd have to figure out how many time multiplication is happening. I wrote it, but I am not sure if I am right - also I need some help with figuring out the multiplication part.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

double intpower(double x, int n)
{
    double result;
    if(n>1&&n%2!=0) {result=x*intpower(x,(n-1)/2)*intpower(x,(n-1)/2);}
    if(n>1&&n%2==0) {result=intpower(x,n/2)*intpower(x,n/2);}
    if(n==1) return x;
    else return result;
}


int main()
{
    int n;
    double x,result;
    printf("x\n");
    scanf("%lf", &x);
    printf("n\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("result = %.2f\n", intpower(x,n));


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "oraz" (apparently) means "and" for those of us who don't speak Polish.

Comment: Yep, sorry for that :D

Comment: You are using `int`.  It it your intention that `intpower()` work for negative numbers?  Else why not use `unsigned` or at least state the limitation?

Comment: Good point, it doesn't really matter though, it's more about the algorithm and how many multiplications are happening.

Comment: But algorithm choices are influence by the scope of the requirements.  If you do not express your requirements clearly, either you get less-than optimal results or put other through unnecessary work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The inductive definitions are saying

1. If k is even, then x^k = [ x^(k/2) ] ^ 2
2. If k is odd, then x^k = x * [ x^(floor(k)/2) ] ^ 2

With these it's a bit easier to see how to arrange the recursion:

```
#include <stdio.h>

double int_pwr(double x, unsigned k)
{
  if (k == 0) return 1;
  if (k == 1) return x;  // This line can be omitted.
  double y = int_pwr(x, k/2);
  return (k & 1) ? x * y * y : y * y;
}

int main(void)
{
  double x;
  unsigned k;
  scanf("%lf%u", &x, &k);
  printf("x^k=%lg\n", int_pwr(x, k));
  return 0;
}
```

I've changed types to be a bit more logical and saved an exponential (in k) amount of work that the OP's solution does by making two recursive calls at each level.

As to the number of multiplications, it's pretty easy to see that if `k`'s highest order bit is 2^p (i.e. at position p), then you'll need p multiplications for the repeated squarings.  Another way of saying this is p = floor(log_2(k)).  For example if k=4=2^2, you'll square the square to get the answer: 2 multiplications.  Additionally you'll need q-1 more, where q is the number of 1's in `k`'s binary rep.  This is the number of times the check for "odd" will be true.  I.e. if k = 5 (which has 2 bits that are 1's), you'll square the square and then multiply the result by `x` one more time.  To summarize, the number of multiplications is p + q - 1 with p and q as defined above.

Comment: What exactly means "return (k & 1) ? x * y * y : y * y;" ?

Comment: You can exclude the `k==1` check. Since 1 is odd, it will multiply `x` by the return value of `int_pwr(x,0)`, which is 1, yielding the correct result.  This does one more iteration but one less check per iteration of the recursion, in the long run that's usually a win.

Comment: `if (k % 2 == 1) { return x * y * y; } else { return y * y; }`

Comment: so if I understand it right, it works exactly the same like my algorithm?

Comment: @pjs  I realize that, but the OP said he had to use the given definition, so I left it in.

Comment: @deviance It means "if k is odd, then the value is `x * y * y`, else it is `y * y`.  It is called the C ternary operator.

Comment: @deviance No it's not exactly the same because your algorithm does unnecessary checks and makes two recursive calls per level, which means much more work than necessary. An extremely aggressive compiler might optimize this away, but it's unlikely.

Comment: @haccks Actually, `&` is the bitwise AND operator, not the logical one.

Answer (score 0):

To figure out how many times multiplication is happening, you could count them in `intpower()`.

```
static int count = 0;
double intpower(double x, int n) {
  double result;
  if(n>1&&n%2!=0) {result=x*intpower(x,(n-1)/2)*intpower(x,(n-1)/2); count += 2;}
  if(n>1&&n%2==0) {result=intpower(x,n/2)*intpower(x,n/2); count++;}
  if(n==1) return x;
  else return result;
}

int main() {
  int n;
  double x,result;
  printf("x\n");
  scanf("%lf", &x);
  printf("n\n");
  scanf("%d", &n);
  mcount = 0;
  printf("result = %.2f\n", intpower(x,n));
  printf("multiplcations = %d\n", mcount);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: That global static variable is horrible and not really necessary -- see the other answer.

Comment: @H2CO3  This negative critique approach lacks tacks as well as justification.  This answer is another approach: not claiming to be superior to others nor necessary – but simple another approach.  Without analyzing the algorithm, it well meets the need.  As many real life problems are beyond trivial analysis, this approach still meets the need.  The use of `static` variables is not in itself `horrible`.  Life critical applications often eschew dynamic allocation preferring a `global` data model.  It has its place.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
double intpower(double x, int n)
{
    if(n == 0) return 1;
    if(n == 1) return x;
    if(n%2!=0)
    {
        return x*intpower(x,(n-1));
    }
    else
    {
        x = intpower(x,n/2);
        return  x*x;
    }

}
```

or you can reduce your function to one line

```
double intpower(double x, int n)
{
    return n == 0 ? 1 : n%2 != 0 ? x*intpower( x, (n-1) ) : (x = intpower(x, n/2), x*x);
}
```

Comment: If you're going to have the `n==1` check at all, it should be returning `x` rather than 0.

Comment: @pjs; That was a typo.